# Embedded NoSQL method for fpga system

Tags: nosql-aggregation

What's a good NoSQL system to use on embedded devices?

- SQLite is too slow for tons of information.
- Will need to run SVM ( Support Vector Machine ) on fpga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What fpga are you using?
- If you're using an embedded system, there few, small NoSQL cores.

I've used Codernity db for ARM based procesors.
You could compile it through cython.

Why not just have the system aquire data then process in amazon ec2?
send back the results